# Маршрутизация ipsec. Как запретить утечку трафика?

Tags: iptables, mikrotik, ipsec

Трафик в туннель направляется не весь, а только тот что указан в адрес листе. Заметил если падает туннель, то трафик начинает идти через дефолтный маршрут, т. е. через провайдера. Как запретить утечку трафика?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: @Духсообщества типичная проблема, вполне понятная

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решается просто.

Нужно создать непривязанный интерфейс, на который попадет трафик пред заворотом в айписек. Тогда трафик вместо ухода в 0.0.0.0 приземлится в этот интерфейс.

[image: микротик айписек]

В микротике добавьте пустой бридж. Добавьте маршрут до защищенной подсети в этот пустой бридж.

```
/interface bridge add name=dummy
/ip route add dst-address=1.1.1.2/32 suppress-hw-offload=yes 
gateway=dummy
```

На линуксах вместо бриджа можно использовать dummy интерфейс.